# mclapply, folds and parameter exploration range

Tags: r, parallel-processing

What would be the "best" or "recommended" way to incorporate both parameter range exploration and cross-validation folds into a single mclapply() command? My concern is that if I'm wrapping mclapply() around the parameter range, some cores may sit idle if some of the cross-validation runs finish before others. My first thought would be to iterate over the cross-product parameter_range X folds, but then this would require some messy assembling of the the CV fold results. I'm using R 2.14 with "parallel".

Comment: Can you give us some (pseudo) code that you're using?

Answer (score 1):

It depends - usually you want to over-feed cores anyway so that if only few processes starve it won't affect performance. If your computation is slow enough, you can disable pre-scheduling so that idle cores will get fed again (there is a considerable penalty for the process management, though). If neither works, you'll have to create the cross-product but the assembling is not really that messy (given constant number of CVs it is actually quite easy).